# How to Find UserControls Control value in Jquery Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I am using jQuery and ASP.net

I have a User Control and wanted to Set the values of this User control to the database, for that I need the user control's value. In the same way, I want to show the data from the database in the user control, for that I need to Get the values by jquery.

In my user control I have 4 TextBoxes and 2 Buttons (SET/UPDATE)

AutoCompleteSearch_New is ascx user control

Here is my tried code:

```
var ID = $('#<%= ((HiddenField)AutoCompleteSearch_New.FindControl("hdnvalue")).ClientID %>').val();
```

But I dont wan't to use hidden fields.

Can I directly find the control's value without using hidden fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to use value from a webform.

Here is the code for the same.

```
 Var TextBoxValue = $('#YourTextBoxID').val();
```

Inspect element and get the Textbox ID and replace it with `YourTextBoxID`.

Or

```
Var TextBoxValue = $('#<%= YourTextBoxID.ClientID').val();
```

where `YourTextBoxID` is your asp:Textbox ID.

When ever you load user control in your aspx page, jquery consider it as a whole page which is combined of user control and rest of the aspx controls exist in the form. So you can directly get textbox value in your jquery

Comment: This is a UserControl not asp control

Comment: Yes I know that. But you can get values same as asp control.

Comment: When ever you load user control in your aspx page, jquery consider it as a whole for which is combined of user control and rest of the aspx controls exist in the form. So you can directly get textbox value in your jquery.

Comment: Yes Iam getting the Result Thanks a Lot

Comment: by the by sir.., how can i bind values to these controls from data base??? Controls which are in User Control agian???

Comment: Yes iam doing all ajax calls ..,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27557/discussion-between-azhar-mansuri-and-pink)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by adding ClientIDMode="Static" to the Control

and then use

```
var txtvalue=  $("#TextBoxId").val();
```

Comment: But that is in UserControl Not asp control

Comment: ClientIDMode="Static" must be for controls in UserControl??

Answer (score 0):

Provided storing the values in Session is not an option, other options I see are :

- javascript variable declaration in the user control markup
- client-side decryption of the view state
- custom data attributes on html elements

I'm afraid HiddenField is your best option. That's somewhat the same idea behind ViewState.

If you don't want the client to tamper with the value, you may go for a combination of the value, and a hash of the value concatenated to a secret key ( value+separator+Hash(value+secretkey) )

If you don't want the client to access the value, you may rely on encrypting it in the HiddenField

Answer (score -1):

hey u can directly find control of textbox or hiddenfield without mention its type

var value=$('AutoCompleteSearch_New_hdnvalue').val();

here AutoCompleteSearch_New is the name of user control u load on page and

hdnvalue is the id of hidden field in user control AutoCompleteSearch_New

enjoy.. :-)