# Unable to find controls in usercontrol using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I am trying to assign click functionality to a button in jQuery. The problem is that button resides in a usercontrol. I am using the following codes for the same -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dvHeader").click(function () {
            alert('test');
        })
    }
    )
</script>
```

The above code works fine if used in a normal .aspx page. i have tried the solution given here [How to Find UserControls Control value in Jquery Asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806272/how-to-find-usercontrols-control-value-in-jquery-asp-net)

But still not working.

Please help in resolving this issue

HTML Code -

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="BookingCancellation.ascx.cs" Inherits="Usercontrols_Sales_BookingCancellation" %>
<script src="../../Javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>


    <div class="divLeft" style="clear: both">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveBottom" SkinID="addButton" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnCancelBottom" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
    </div>
```

I have called the script on this usercontrol only.

Comment: show us the output html.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wont have `ClientIDMode="Static"` and need to use ClientID for javascript. Either set `ClientIDMode="Static"` or use `ClientID`, you can read more over [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= dvHeader.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            alert('test');
        });
    });
</script>
```

There is error in the accepted answer solution second part,

```
$('#<%= YourTextBoxID.ClientID').val();
```

Would be

```
$('#<%= YourTextBoxID.ClientID %>').val();
```

Comment: I have already added ClientIDMode="Static" in my HTML. I have tried your code also. It's still not working :(

Comment: I have tried adding jquery file reference using url also. Like [Link]http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js